# Duplicate data in object setter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a user object I'm using with scoped model:

```
class User extends Model {
    String name;
    String description;
    // and a bunch of other fields

    User(Map data) {
        this.name = data['name'];
        this.description = data['description'];
    }

    void updateUser(Map data) {
        // copy and pasted from User constructor
        this.name = data['name'];
        this.description = data['description'];

        notifyListeners();        
    }
}
```

Is there a way not have to duplicate the code from the User constructor inside updateUser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be one way to do it:

```
class User extends Model {
    String name;
    String description;
    // and a bunch of other fields

    User(Map data) {
        updateUser(data, notify: false);
    }

    void updateUser(Map data, {bool notify = true}) {
        // copy and pasted from User constructor
        this.name = data['name'];
        this.description = data['description'];

        if(notify) {
            notifyListeners();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it'll look simpler if you call the first constructor inside the update method.
call "User(data)" inside them you can follow with "notifyListeners();"